# Target Database always reverts to "master" in my SQL Server Database Project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-project

I'm starting a SQL Server 2008 database project that's pointed to a specific target database. However, everytime I set the target database in the project properties, it reverts back to the master database. What's going on, here??

Comment: So you're saying when you execute `use YourDbName` it reverts back to the `master` db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the "SQL Server 2008 Server Project" template, not the "SQL Server 2008 Database Project" template.  The server templates will always set the target database to master.